# Group by Rollup not rolling up - Except in 1 case

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I want to perform a group by rollup calculation (I know varchar as ID is bad - it's out of my control)

The query is correct insofar as each individual department but the sub-departments are not being included

I want to retrieve all job applications with status hired rolled up by its departments "ancestor_ids" - a list of all of its parent departments in descending order. i.e:

`ancestor_ids: [parent, child, grandchild, great-grandchild, etc...]`

Departments with no ancestors have an empty list:
`ancestor_ids: []`

Imagine a schema such:

Note: Varchar is "character varying(255)"

```sql
-- table job_applications
id   varchar
job_id   varchar
status   varchar
archived_at   timestamp without time zone


-- table jobs
id    varchar
name    varchar
department_ids    character varying(255)[]

-- table departments
id    varchar
ancestor_ids    character varying(255)[]
name    varchar
```

Imagine a dataset such that:

```
-- departments
id: Engineering
ancestor_ids: {}

id: SoftwareEngineering
ancestor_ids: {Engineering}

id: DevOps
ancestor_ids: {Engineering, SoftwareEngineering}

id: OtherDepartment
ancestor_ids: {}
```

When I retrieve all hires, I want to see something like:

```
count 25
department_names OtherDepartment (x5) Engineering (x10) SoftwareEngineering (x5) DevOps (x5)
all_ids {OtherDepartment, Engineering, SoftwareEngineering, DevOps}

count  20
department_names Engineering (x10) SoftwareEngineering (x5) DevOps (x5)
all_ids {Engineering, SoftwareEngineering, DevOps}

count 10
department_names SoftwareEngineering (x5) Devops (x5)
all_ids {SoftwareEngineering, DevOps}

count 5
department_names DevOps (x5)
all_ids {DevOps}
```

Right now, only individual departments are included with the exception of the total, where it is correct. It looks something like:

```sql
count 25
department_names OtherDepartment (x5) Engineering (x10) SoftwareEngineering (x5) DevOps (x5)
all_ids {OtherDepartment, Engineering, SoftwareEngineering, DevOps}

count  10
department_names Engineering (x10)
all_ids {Engineering, SoftwareEngineering, DevOps}

count 5
department_names SoftwareEngineering (x5)
all_ids {SoftwareEngineering, DevOps}

count 5
department_names DevOps (x5)
all_ids {DevOps}
```

The numbers are *correct*, but they're not grouped / summed the way I would expect them to be. Here's my query (Postgres 14):

```sql
select count(ja.id)
  string_agg(d.name, ', ') as department_names
  (d.id || d.ancestor_ids) as all_ids
from job_applications ja
left join jobs j on j.id = ja.id
left join departments d
  on d.id = ANY(j.department_ids) -- I am almost certain this is the culprit and I need a subquery or similar here
  group by rollup(all_ids)
  order by count desc;
```

Thank you for reading and I appreciate your time

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith - For the most part, yes, there will be only one value in the list. Unfortunately I do not control the data source. There can be more than 1 value in `department_ids`, so it must be an array. Thanks for taking the time to look